# android horizontal orientation of layout with FrameLayout and Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have a design problem with Android. I wan't to make two fragments load side by side in horizontal orientation. Here is the main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:elevation="7sp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BaseActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!--
    Material design toolbar
    -->
    <include android:id="@+id/tool_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- Second FrameLayout for details -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailscontainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF3300"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>


<!-- Nav drawer -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer" />
```

I inflate this in `@+id/container`

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/api_error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fffcac"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/api_error_text"
        android:text="@string/no_ObavijestiData"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/content_padding_normal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#999999"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And populate `ListView` in code. But nothing is shown... If I put `android:orientation="verical"` in main.xml and replace height and width values, I can see both fragments but they are one below another. Can anybody help??

Comment: You are checking on which kind of device?

Comment: For now, on Emulator - TABLET

Comment: Can you check on tablet emulator, i guess its not showing because you are checking on mobile device emulator

Comment: I am checking it on Tablet Emulator.